# pcap_next() function should be put before the packet transmission or after?

Tags: c, networking, libpcap

I want to capture the ACK packet in a tcp-3way handshake using libpcap
the code snippet is as below

```
   pcap_packet = pcap_next(pcap_handler, &pcap_header);
    if(pcap_packet !=NULL)
            printf("capture one packet with length of %d\n", pcap_header.len);

    // establish TCP connection with the server
    connect(sd_cli, (struct sockaddr *)&svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr));

    process(pcap_packet);
```

I'm wondering whether I should put the  pcap_next() function before connect() or after connect()? I'm a bit lost in the callback function mechanism

can anyone explain a bit with this example? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should capture packets **concurrent** to transmission. So, it's better to use threads.

But in your case, put `connect` before `pcap_next` has better chances to capture what you need. However, `connect` itself is a blocking method and maybe you lose packets.

Comment: then, how to synchronize the thread? to make them run accurately simultaneously ?

Comment: why `connect` before `pcap_next`? after `connect`, the packets are already received, and after it is received, then `pcap_next` is called, it seems `pcap_next` will capture nothing?

Comment: You don't need an accrue synchronization, capture packets in a thread and filter them to collect what do you want.

Comment: does the returned packet includes ethernet header?